# What does this symbol on a door mean? (福)

Tags: factoids, culture, public-holidays, asia, cultural-awareness

I live in the Czech Republic in an area where many nationalities live.

This year I noticed this strange symbol on multiple doors, although I am sure it has never been there before.

[image: symbol]

What does it mean? What culture uses it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: @fkraiem We have questions about cultural differences and aspects of other countries. It's not that far fetched.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the Chinese character for "Good Fortune" 福. January 28 was the Chinese (Lunar) New Year.